# NGRX Effect "rxjs reducer operator" stop the observable chain

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am working on an Angular project with NGRX store and effect inside. I got a problem when using *rxjs reducer operator*, the observable chain somehow was stopped. No errors are shown on the console.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyEffects {
    @Effect()
    public grouping$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(FIRST_ACTION),
        map((action) => action.payload),
        flatMap(i => i),
        groupBy((i) => i.code),
        flatMap(group$ => {
            return group$.pipe(
                reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    acc.push(curr);
                    console.log('%c curr', 'background-color:green;color:#fff', curr);
                    console.log('%c acc', 'background-color:green;color:#fff', acc);
                    return acc;
                }, []),
                tap(grpArr => console.log('group array', grpArr))
            );
        }),
        switchMap((data) => {
            return [new AnotherAction()];
        })
    );
}
```

My concern is on the line

> tap(grpArr => console.log('group array', grpArr))

The reducer operators logs the right output in the console. But when I tap the result, they are not showing. And of course the last switchMap operator not trigger since the chain is stopped. Am I missing something here?

Console output for reducer operator
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by results are not showing? how you are printing results?

Comment: @rijin
i log it using tap operator after the reducer 
tap(grpArr => console.log('group array', grpArr))

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to be using [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan) instead of [`reduce`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-reduce) because `reduce` will emit the accumulated value only **when its source completes**.

However, `this.actions$` never completes so `group$` never completes and thus `reduce` never emits anything.

On the other hand `scan` will emit each intermediate result. I don't know if that's what you want so you might have to chain with `filter` or something.

Comment: Yes true, but in this case tap will print empty array.

Comment: `tap` will print what you return from `scan`

Comment: I use reducer here because groupBy will return two observables with different key. 
Then I need to transform the *GroupObservable* into array. Before this I use to array insted of reducer, but still no luck. 

If I use scan operator, the result will emit one by one. Not in a array group. 

`[
  {
    "id": "34104",
    "newAmount": 10
  },
  {
    "id": "34104",
    "newAmount": 1000010
  },
  {
    "id": "32103",
    "newAmount": 10
  }
]`

this is the output when I use scan. Id is not group